# CSS: margin-top collapsing

Tags: css

My caveat is I'm not a web designer, I'm a technician.

I want the following CSS to apply, but it looks like there is a margin collapse going on:

```
.site-info .site-title {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

[JSfiddle: here](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/x6e65efa/2/).

HTML:

```
<div class="site-info"> <span class="site-title">© 2016 <a href="#" rel="home"><strong>Non-Web Designer</strong></a></span>
  <div class="menu-footer-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer-menu-2" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-71"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"><a href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-footer {
    margin-top: 0;  
}
.site-footer .site-title::after {
    content: " ";
}
.site-info {
    border-top: 1px #9b998b solid;
    padding: 1px;
}
.site-info .site-title {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.site-info a {
    color: #686868;
}
#site-navigation .menu-footer-menu-container {
    float: none
}
.menu-footer-menu-container {
    float: right;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul {
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}
footer .menu-footer-menu-container ul li {display: inline-block; padding: 1em;}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul li:hover {background-color: #E7E3D2;}
```

I've added a border and padding to the parent container (which I thought was the solution to the border collapse issue:

```
.site-info {
    border-top: 1px #9b998b solid;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

but the issue remains.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Look at [mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Comment: You could use padding top instead (would need the span to be inline-block)?  That way it will be applied to both elements

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Pete. If you add an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`:

```
.site-info .site-title {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

But you would also need to make your span an inline-block or block element so that the padding applies:

```
.site-title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `padding-top` property, unless you're applying a different `background-color` to one of them, it should work for you. Alternatively only use `padding-top` for the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Give `inline-block` to the element. By default `display: inline` was applied to the element. That's why the element didn't respect the `margin` .

Or you can use `padding` instead.

```
.site-info .site-title {
    margin-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x6e65efa/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

"span" is an "inline" element, which means that it will not be bothered by your margin. You can either change

```
<span class="site-title">...
```

Into:

```
<div class="site-title">...
```

Or set a css property to make it behave like a block element:

```
.site-title{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try " float:left; " in this class " .site-info .site-title " .

```css
.site-footer {
    margin-top: 0;  
}
.site-footer .site-title::after {
    content: " ";
}
.site-info {
    border-top: 1px #9b998b solid;
    padding: 1px;
}
.site-info .site-title {
    margin-top: 1em;
  float: left;
}
.site-info a {
    color: #686868;
}
#site-navigation .menu-footer-menu-container {
    float: none
}
.menu-footer-menu-container {
    float: right;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul {
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}
footer .menu-footer-menu-container ul li {display: inline-block; padding: 1em;}
.menu-footer-menu-container ul li:hover {background-color: #E7E3D2;}
```

```html
<div class="site-info"> <span class="site-title">© 2016 <a href="#" rel="home"><strong>Non-Web Designer</strong></a></span>
  <div class="menu-footer-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer-menu-2" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-71"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"><a href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change your css to:

```
.site-info .site-title{
    display:block;
   .margin-top:1em;
}
```

it will work